# Gimp clears the clipboard of character data

Tags: gimp, text, character

When attempting to paste from the clipboard into GIMP 2.10.36 the statusbar says there's no image data in the clipboard to paste. There's no image data, true, but there is character data there that gets ignored.

1. What happens to the character data it ignores,
2. and how do I copy character data into GIMP?

Comment: By "character data", do you mean text? If yes, you probably need a text object to paste into.

Comment: Photoshop does the same thing.. if the clipboard contains text, you have to have a text object active in order to paste text - otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: 1. Nothing happens to it. 2. Use the text tool, click and drag on the canvas to create a text object (a text box), then paste.

Comment: I had been repeatedly using Command-V in an attempt to paste the text contents of the clipboard into one of GIMP's text fields, but that failed. What did work was creating a text field, right clicking, and selecting “Paste” from the hierarchical menu.

Comment: That sounds like a potential bug. You should probably [report it](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues).  I can't reproduce the problem in Windows. Maybe a Mac issue, or a recent bug even? Did you make sure your cursor was inside the text box?

Comment: @BillyKerr That cursor focus is a good reminder, thank you. Thank you also for the hotlink on the “report it” suggestion, too. Little things like that say a lot about your character.

Comment: 1st, I'm using Flycut, a multi-clipboard manager. Maybe that's introducing something in the way of things.

Secondly, with the text insertion cursor inside the text box, I find that 

1. Command-V won't paste the text content
2. Edit > Paste won't paste the text content
3. but right clicking inside the text box > Paste *will* paste the text content

Is it like that for Windows too?

Sound like a bug? 

Please comment.

Comment: In Windows, you don't need to right click anything. Just create a text box and hit Edit > Paste, or use the Shortuct Ctrl+V to paste.  There is a possibility that a third party clipboard app could be messing with the paste functionality. Can you uninstall it or disable it to test?

Comment: Disabling Flycut, the same symptoms appear as 1, 2, 3 before, above. I'm calling bug and making a bug report.